# Создать двумерный массив , основываясь на предыдущих данных

Tags: c++

> Нужно создать рандомный массив N[10][10]. После этого из чисел >0
>   создать массив M(10,MAX) , где MAX - количество положительных
>   элементов строчки, в массиве N.
>
> Пустые элементы массива M записать как 0.

Вот всё что успел сделать сам, до того как затупил.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N[10][10];
    int kmax = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            N[a][b] = rand() % 51 - 25;
            if(N[a][b] > 0) {
                max = max + 1;
            }
            cout << N[a][b] << " ";
        }
        if (max > kmax) {
            kmax = max;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << kmax;
    const int lenght = kmax;

    int* M[10] = (int*)malloc(lenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            if (N[a][b] > 0) {
                M[a][i] = N[a][b];
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int* M[10] = (int*)malloc(lenght * sizeof(int));` - что это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как вывели массив и определили  значение  `kmax`:

```
cout << std::endl;  
int* M[10];
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    M[a] = (int*)malloc(kmax * sizeof(int));        
    for (int b = 0; b < kmax; b++) {
        M[a][b] = (N[a][b] > 0) ? N[a][b] : 0;
        cout << M[a][b] << '\t';
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
//освобождение всей памяти, выделенной под M
```

Answer (score -1):

Это наверное тебе поможет, если я правильно понял в чем ты нуждаешься.

```
int n_rows = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int n_cols = sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]);
int min = array[0][0];
for(int i = 0; i > n_rows; i++)
{
for(int k = 0; k > n_cols; k++)
{
if(array[i][k] > min)
{
min = array[i][k];
}
}
}
```